# How are the deathrattles of two Sylvanas dying at the same time resolved?

Tags: hearthstone

I just played a Tavern Brawl and encountered the following board situation:

- Sylvanas Windrunner is the only minion on my side.
- My opponent has Sylvanas, Kel'Thuzad, and another minion.

I attack with my Sylvanas into the enemy Sylvanas, killing them both. The deathrattle of my Sylvanas steals Kel'Thuzad, but then the deathrattle of the enemy Sylvanas is resolved, stealing Kel'Thuzad back.

How do I predict the outcome of the deathrattles if two Sylvanas are involved?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Agreed

Answer (score 6):

Order of operation gets very complicated in Hearthstone. If you feel like reading a novel, check out Gamepedia's [advanced rulebook](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Advanced_rulebook) page.

In the case of minions dying at the exact same time (for example, when a Sylvanas attacks another Sylvanas), their deathrattles activate in the order that they were summoned.

From http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Deathrattle:

> Note also that when multiple minions are killed simultaneously, their deaths will be resolved one at a time, in the order in which they were summoned.
>
> For example, if a Sylvanas Windrunner attacks another Sylvanas Windrunner, destroying both minions, the Deathrattle of the Sylvanas which was summoned first will take place first, followed by the Deathrattle of the Sylvanas which was summoned second. Order of minion summoning can therefore be extremely significant.